# Combining table into a row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would really appreciate some help with the following query. I need the following table to be listed as one entire row:

```
10/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30
11/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30
12/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30
13/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30
14/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30
```

and i need it to be combined as such:

```
10/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30 - 11/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30 - 12/12/2018  08:00   18:30   08:00   18:30
```

I have tried transpose, offset and vlookup and some of the answers on this website but it is not specific to my query. If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much cleaner solution, but for something quick. In the cells below the source add a mid formula, then the row below that add a mid-formula referencing a cell the row above which is an accumulation of the total characters in the mid-formula to create a new starting point for the mid-formula. Use that to break it all apart then bring it back together with a concatenate formula spacing out with the desired:
[image]

=CONCATENATE(A2,"-",A3,"-",A4,"-",A5,"-",A6)